# calculating medians per year per ID in R and plotting the outcome

Tags: r, dataframe, lm

Dataset:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
1234, 8769, 8769, 8769, 8769, 8769, 7457, 7457, 7457, 7457, 7457, 
7457, 55667, 55667, 55667, 55667, 55667, 55667, 55667, 3789, 
3789, 3789, 3789, 3789, 3789), date_of_bloods = structure(c(978307200, 
981072000, 1173052800, 1175731200, 1367798400, 1465171200, 1467936000, 
1659916800, 1072915200, 1075680000, 1173052800, 1175731200, 1367798400, 
978307200, 981072000, 1173052800, 1175731200, 1367798400, 1465171200, 
978307200, 981072000, 1173052800, 1270425600, 1273104000, 1465171200, 
1467936000, 1270425600, 1367798400, 1465171200, 1465257600, 1465344000, 
1465430400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    result = c(90, 80, 60, 40, 25, 22, 22, 21, 70, 65, 43, 23, 
    22, 90, 90, 88, 86, 76, 74, 58, 46, 35, 34, 33, 30, 24, 76, 
    67, 56, 34, 33, 23), `mutation type` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like the median of results per year per ID in a format where the year is just 0,1,2,3 etc for uniformity across cohorts and then to plot these lines with some indication of their mutation category.

I have done:

```
filtered$date_of_bloods <-format(filtered$date_of_bloods,format="%Y")
#split into individual ID groups
a <- with(filtered, split(filtered, list(ID)))

#aggregate median results per year 
medianfunc <- function(y) {aggregate(results ~ date_of_bloods, data = y, median)}
medians <- sapply(a, medianfunc)

# do lm per ID cohort and get slope of lines 
g<- as.data.frame(medians)
coefLM <- function(x) {coef(lm(date_of_bloods ~ results, data = x))}
coefs<- sapply(g, coefLM)
```

The actual years don't matter and for uniformity I would like them to be 0,1,2,3,4 etc per ID. I am not sure how to do that? I would then want to plot this data (median yearly bloods per ID) with some form of idea as to which mutational category they belong.

I hope this isn't too broad a question.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (`filtered` is the `dput()` you included). I hope this helps:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
#Data
filtered %>% mutate(year=year(date_of_bloods)) %>%
group_by(ID,year,`mutation type`) %>% summarise(med=median(result)) -> df1
#Variables
df1 %>% ungroup()%>% mutate(ID=as.factor(ID),
                            year=as.factor(year),
                            `mutation type`=as.factor(`mutation type`)) -> df1
#Plot
ggplot(df1,aes(x=ID,y=med,fill=`mutation type`,color=year,group=year))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

And for models:

```
#Models
fits <- df1 %>%group_by(ID) %>% 
  do(fitmodel = lm(med ~ year, data = .))
#Coefs
dfCoef = tidy(fits, fitmodel)


# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   ID [5]
      ID term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  1234 (Intercept)  6329.    1546.         4.09  0.0264
 2  1234 year           -3.13     0.769     -4.07  0.0268
 3  3789 (Intercept) 14318.    4746.         3.02  0.204 
 4  3789 year           -7.08     2.36      -3.00  0.205 
 5  7457 (Intercept)  2409.     403.         5.98  0.0269
 6  7457 year           -1.16     0.201     -5.78  0.0287
 7  8769 (Intercept)  9268.    4803.         1.93  0.304 
 8  8769 year           -4.60     2.39      -1.92  0.306 
 9 55667 (Intercept)  3294.     759.         4.34  0.0492
10 55667 year           -1.62     0.378     -4.29  0.0503
```

**Code for required plot:**

```
#Plot 2
#Data modifications
df1 %>% mutate(year2=as.numeric(year)-1) -> df2
df2 %>% mutate(year2=factor(year2,levels = sort(unique(year2)))) -> df2
#Plot 2
ggplot(df2,aes(x=year2,y=med,color=ID,group=ID))+
  facet_wrap(.~`mutation type`)+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer! up until generating df1 that is exactly as I need. However, I would then want to turn year into 0,1,2,3 etc from earliest year to latest and then create a plot where x are the transformed years in number 0->n and the y-axis is the median for that year with each line a different ID. If the lines could be coded for mutation type that would be perfect.

Comment: @tacrolimus Hi. I have added a new code for the plot you want. I hope this helps.

Comment: dear @Duck many thanks again for helping. The df part works perfectly again. However, in reality there are over 200 IDs in my dataset and I get a plot with lots of IDs as individual plots. If I just wanted to simply it and plot x=year2 y=median per ID how would I do that? Do the plots auto-generate a key that is hiding the actual main plot?

Comment: @tacrolimus You could try `facet_wrap(.~ID)` or remove the wrap and `color=ID` and `group=ID`

Comment: @tacrolimus I meant keep `color=ID` and `group=ID` you can play around it. I believe the hard part is done. Let me know if I can help you.

Comment: Thanks again, I will play around with the data and try and get the plots going. You've been very kind!

Answer (score 0):

Your naming structure is unclear, if the data you provided is called `df` then you can do:

```
df$year <-format(df$date_of_bloods,format="%Y")
aggregate(result ~ year + ID, data = df, median)

   year    ID result
1  2001  1234   85.0
2  2007  1234   50.0
3  2013  1234   25.0
4  2016  1234   22.0
5  2022  1234   21.0
6  2010  3789   76.0
7  2013  3789   67.0
8  2016  3789   33.5
9  2001  7457   90.0
10 2007  7457   87.0
11 2013  7457   76.0
12 2016  7457   74.0
13 2004  8769   67.5
14 2007  8769   33.0
15 2013  8769   22.0
16 2001 55667   52.0
17 2007 55667   35.0
18 2010 55667   33.5
19 2016 55667   27.0
```